# Are TFS Release Manager Templates versionable?

Tags: tfs, version-control, ms-release-management

How do I (is it possible to) store my release management templates under version control? It seems as though this should be something that I should be able to version alongside the codebase that it's deploying.

Comment: Don't think you can if you are talking about the original VS Release Management. Also, in my experience VS Release Management leads users who are likely to be implementing non-trivial deployments down the wrong path. This is because it's based on workflow 'tasks' which turn out to be very inflexible when it comes to implementing the same workflow in other environments. The smart money is looking like a PowerShell script (refactored) that lives with, is versioned with, and builds with the code and can be applied to any environment via parameters. This PowerShell is triggered by a single task.

Comment: Er, yes, I meant VS2013 Release Management. I've inherited a (allegedly) functioning system, but it would appear that there's no ability to figure out who makes changes or if they make catastrophic changes, no ability to roll back to previous versions - which seems like a huge issue that should be mitigated.

Comment: You should also note that the RM Services (Release Management vNext) does have a form of versioning the deployment templates (including who made the changes).

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you don't. Release Management Server stores its release templates as Windows Workflow XAML, with a lot of links to things that only live in the Release Management database. [Ask me how I know!](https://github.com/ALM-Rangers/Migrate-assets-from-RM-server-to-VSTS)

You can accomplish what you're after (and be more future-proof in the process) by writing your deployment scripts as PowerShell or Desired State Configuration scripts, then source controlling them and dropping them alongside your build. Then you can just have Release Management invoke your scripts, which eliminates a good bit of the versioning concern.

If you're interested in extracting the deployment logic in agent-based workflows, take a look at the link I provided -- the ALM Rangers released a tool to translate agent-based release templates into PowerShell scripts. Full disclosure: I am a major contributor to the project.